# Multiple Markers on Googlemaps api

Tags: c#, javascript, google-maps, kml, marker

I want to add multiple markers on a map. The amount is variable (one to a few hundred)
Which is the best solution?

1. Producing a kml file with the coordinates
2. Using javascript and creating via (in my case) c# a lot of marker
   variables
3. another way i didn't think of

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustering!
See this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers
I use this solution in my actual project.

Example:

```
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-17.308688,-49.495605);
 var myLatlng, marker, marker_cluster;
 var markers = [];

 var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        minZoom: 4,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0'
 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

$.each(itens, function (k, iten) {
        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(iten.lat, iten.lng);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            title: iten.title
        });

        markers.push(marker);
    });

marker_cluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

Comment: Thank you, but clustering is about the handling the markers. I am not sure how I should include them (via kml or javascript variables). What do you use?

Comment: see the additional comment that I placed above

Comment: Ah very nice. That looks really nice. I think this is exactly what i need.
I am not very good with jQuery. Is itens an object which contains the coordinates?
(I have all the coordinates in a database)

Comment: Oh! Excuse me, i forgot to talk about it. Yes, the items have the coordinates. In my case i using Postgres with PostGIS to store the coordinates

Comment: No problem and thank you very much. How do you get the coordinates in itens?

Comment: Using PostGIS is simple. In Python file, after receiving the return on my DB, I try iten.x and iten.y. In C# i don't know, but should be something like this.